# Vsphere storage usage shown is different on vm

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, vsphere, vcenter

Im using vSphere 7.0.3 with ubuntu 20.4 vm and VMware Tools version:11360,
The issue is that we created a vm from vm snapshot -> and then from that vm we created a vm from its snapshot and so on..

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                  12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                 2.4G  4.4M  2.4G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu.                 61G   13G   46G  22% /
/dev/sdc1                          288G   30G  244G  11% /mounts 
/dev/sdb1                          192G   21G  161G  12% /var/lib/docker
```

As we can see there is less the 70G in use
but in the vspere i see "storage usage" is 250G

if i go to datastore where this vm is on its still doesnt add up to 250G

```
vswp   25,165,824 KB
1.vmdk 2,340,864 KB
2.vmdk 1,380,352 KB
3.vmdk 162,816 KB
```

On this current vm there is no snapshot, im gussing we made this issue because wed cloned from snapshots multiple times, but is there a way to fix this?

I have tried runing

```
sudo vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrinkonly
```

but i get an error

```
The shrink feature is not available,

either because you are running an old version of a VMware product, or because too many communication channels are open.

If you are running an old version of a VMware product, you should consider upgrading.

If too many communication channels are open, you should power off your virtual machine and then power it back on.
```

I think i cannot use it as this vm parent file has at least 5-7 layers over it.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I cannot use it as this vm parent file has at least 5-7 layers
> over it.

Probably very true.

Snapshots are use to test a concept and then combine into the base machine if the test is good. They are not best used to create the base machine.

While snapshots can be used to back up, I do not regard this as a good strategy. Use the proper backup methods for your version of VMware.  For me, I make a backup of the folder.

Create your parent (base) Ubuntu machine from the Ubuntu ISO and install it properly.

This will work. I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS running a VM in VMware - works great.